# sockaddr struct usage in mongoose.c example

Tags: mongoose, ip, ipv4

I've been going through an old mongoose.c code found in http://docs.ros.org/en/diamondback/api/jpeg_streamer/html/mongoose_8c_source.html

I would like some help understanding (in detail if possible) why at the `bind()` and `accept()` syscall the **sockaddr** is used instead of the **sockaddr_in**

Here is the definition of the Unified socket address:

```
union usa {
  struct sockaddr sa;
  struct sockaddr_in sin;
};
```

The `bind()` and `accept()` calls:

```
bind(sock, &so.lsa.u.sa, so.lsa.len)
...
accept(listener->sock, &accepted.rsa.u.sa, &accepted.rsa.len)
```

To rephrase: In these two calls an address value is set to the **sockaddr** field of the struct, but in every other function involving the sockets (e.g. parse_port_string), the addresses are read an written to the **sockaddr_in** field of the struct. How can this work?